# How to remove commas from a number when it's combined with a string

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to combine a string field and a number field into one
It is displaying as OP1,572,915.00 when I need it to display as OP1572915
The number field can be between 0 - 10 digits long
How do I remove the commas because there is not option when I try to format the field[image: How do I remove commas?]

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula and type this thing in it:

```
{MyTable.OP} + ' ' + ToText({MyTable.Num}, 0, '')
```

then use this formula in your report.